# STRING cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java

**ERROR :**
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
STRING cannot be resolved or is not a field,NUMERIC cannot be resolved or is not a field,BOOLEAN cannot be resolved or is not a field,BLANK cannot be resolved or is not a field. I am using below code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator; 
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String filename = "test.xlsx";

        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename)) {
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();
                while (cells.hasNext()) {
                    HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();

                    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType type = cell.getCellTypeEnum();
                    if (type == CellType.STRING) {
                        System.out.println("[" + cell.getRowIndex() + ", "
                                + cell.getColumnIndex() + "] = STRING; Value = "
                                + cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString());
                    } else if (type == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        System.out.println("[" + cell.getRowIndex() + ", "
                                + cell.getColumnIndex() + "] = NUMERIC; Value ="
                                + cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    } else if (type == CellType.BOOLEAN) {
                        System.out.println("[" + cell.getRowIndex() + ", "
                                + cell.getColumnIndex() + "] = BOOLEAN; Value ="
                                + cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                    } else if (type == CellType.BLANK) {
                        System.out.println("[" + cell.getRowIndex() + ", "
                                + cell.getColumnIndex() + "] = BLANK CELL");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `getCellType()` instead of `getCellTypeEnum()`, the former method seems to be deprecated anyway (since POI 3.15) : https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellTypeEnum-- .

Answer (score 0):

Try to import `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType`.

This `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType type = cell.getCellTypeEnum();` is working but you don't call `CellType` the same way on next lines.

Comment: Thank you for the quick help. I am getting the below error when i run the code.Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.

Comment: That's another problem. You should carefully read the official document of the library you are using. The error seems to tell you that you are parsing an office 2007 document. This part of the library may be used for 2010+ documents.

Comment: @sharath You can provide file type check before parsing like `if (file.getOriginalFilename().endsWith(".xls")) {...}` OR `if (file.getOriginalFilename().endsWith(".xlsx")) {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version **poi-4.0.1** Change all your if condition should simply be :

```
 if (type == STRING) {
          // ..............
          // ..............
   } else if (type == NUMERIC) {
        // ..............
        // ..............
   } else if (type == BOOLEAN) {
        // ..............
        // ..............
  } else if (type == BLANK) {
       // ..............
      // ..............
                    }
                }
```